# Tooltipster worked. Now : TypeError: $('.tooltip').tooltipster is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I'm rebuilding a simple html/css website meant to be available in 2 languages. French and english. Both need tooltipster.
It is working perfectly on the french page. But not at all on the english page.

Error :

> TypeError: $('.tooltip').tooltipster is not a function. (In '$('.tooltip').tooltipster(
>           )', '$('.tooltip').tooltipster' is undefined)

The function is define this way in the html.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

Why is it not working when the english page is the exact copy of the french page ?

Visible at : [www.krypton.fr/krypton3/index.html](http://www.krypton.fr/krypton3/index.html) ( for the french page )
[www.krypton.fr/krypton3/index-en.html](http://www.krypton.fr/krypton3/index-en.html) ( for the english page )

Comment: check where jQuery is included in -en page. It is included twice.

Comment: Thank you. I checked several times. Rebuild the damn page. The computer and I are getting too old :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an exact copy, you have two scripts included twice on english page, which probably causes the error:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I swear I was on that thing for hours yesterday. Rebuild the page several times. My computer and I are getting too old.