# TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I used the docs in the main website to setup a simple tooltip, but can't seem to get it to work.

Using Chrome's console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function
```

I've been trying to find a duplicate of jQuery (as it was a solution provided in here: [Tooltipster worked. Now : TypeError: $('.tooltip').tooltipster is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890737/tooltipster-worked-now-typeerror-tooltip-tooltipster-is-not-a-function)), but I can't seem to get with it.

Here's the site: http://badia.me/amir/

The tooltipster should be over the "Some text" text (I used the docs example to minimize the changes of me screwing up).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you include the library?

Comment: Look at the network tab. http://badia.me/js/tooltipster.core.min.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you don't have tooltipster included. The reference you have goes to a 404

This:

```
<script href="/js/tooltipster.core.min.js"></script>
```

Leads to this:

http://badia.me/js/tooltipster.core.min.js

It should be:

http://badia.me/amir/js/tooltipster.core.min.js

Also on a side note, use absolute paths for sourcing files as just part defining will cause issues with sub directories.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed the link (and the JS works), but I get the same error.

Comment: Take the call out of the head and put it at the bottom of the document before the </body> tag

Comment: Did that and I still get the same error. I tried putting it in its own <script> tag and inside another one (so the two (document).ready wouldn't conflict), but I get the same result.